# Sort a list of lists by length and value in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

How can I sort a Python list (with sublists)? For example, I have the following list:

```
list1 = [[0, 4, 1, 5], [3, 1, 5], [4, 0, 1, 5]]
```

After sorting I am expecting:

```
list1 = [[3, 1, 5], [0, 4, 1, 5], [4, 0, 1, 5]]
```

Another example. I have the following list:

```
list2 = [[4, 5, 2], [2, 5, 4], [2, 4, 5]]
```

After sorting I am expecting:

```
list2 = [[2, 4, 5], [2, 5, 4], [4, 5, 2]]
```

At first I want to sort by length, and then by itemwise in each sublist. **I do not want to sort any sublist.**

I have tried the following code, which helped me to sort by length only:

```
list1.sort(key=len)
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need a key like:

```
lambda l: (len(l), l)
```

#### How:

This uses a [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) to create a [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) which can the be used by [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) to sort in the desired fashion. This works because tuples sort element by element.

#### Test Code:

```
list1 = [[0, 4, 1, 5], [3, 1, 5], [4, 0, 1, 5]]
print(sorted(list1, key=lambda l: (len(l), l)))

list2 = [[4, 5, 2], [2, 5, 4], [2, 4, 5]]
print(sorted(list2, key=lambda l: (len(l), l)))
```

#### Results:

```
[[3, 1, 5], [0, 4, 1, 5], [4, 0, 1, 5]]
[[2, 4, 5], [2, 5, 4], [4, 5, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's list.sort() method is "stable", i. e. the relative order of items that compare equal does not change. Therefore you can also achieve the desired order by calling sort() twice:

```
>>> list1 = [[3, 1, 5], [0, 4, 1, 5], [4, 0, 1, 5]]
>>> list1.sort()  # sort by sublist contents
>>> list1.sort(key=len)  # sort by sublist length
>>> list1
[[3, 1, 5], [0, 4, 1, 5], [4, 0, 1, 5]]
```